# Finite sum of complex exponentials giving wrong result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, summation

I was playing with the following sum:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{2} e^{\frac{2\pi i k^2}{3}} = e^{0} + e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}} + e^{\frac{8\pi i}{3}} \ne 0, $$

which is non-zero, at least according to [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2Be%5E%282*pi*i%2F3%29%20%2B%20e%5E%284*2*pi%2F3%29).

I tried to calculate the sum in Mathematica with:

```
Sum[Exp[(k*k) * 2*Pi*I/n], {k, 0, n - 1}] /. n -> 3
```

which I intepreted to mean $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{k^2 \frac{2\pi i}{n}}, \quad n = 3.$$

But the behavior of this is unexpected because the result is 0:

[image]

I feel most likely that I have failed to communicate my mathematical "intent", but having used the `Sum` function successfully in the past, I'm a bit surprised.

A hint behind the bug seems that even if I don't substitute *any* variables, it still comes out as 0. See this:

```
Sum[Exp[(i^2) * 2*Pi*I/n], {i, 0, n - 1}]
```

[image]

Something feels wrong, however, as

```
Sum[i^2, {i, 0, 5}]
```

still seems to work the normal way:

[image]

Therefore, I don't believe I am using the `Sum` function incorrectly.

Also, when I hard code numbers, it does seem to work correctly:

```
Sum[Exp[(i^2) * 2*Pi*I/5], {i, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

It looks like the presence of $n$ is causing the result to be incorrect.

Comment: V 13.3.1 on windows gives this   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUwOn.png)

Comment: @creidhne ive added some of the missing snippets.

Comment: @Nasser i'm running mathematica 13.0.1 student edition on a macbook pro.

Comment: Then this looks like a bug that was fixed since?

Comment: Is the implication I need to upgrade my mathematica version? I feel like something is suspicious if a simple sum involving complex exponentials is breaking. I'm a very new user so I'm more likely to have made a mistake perhaps during setup using the tool than to have found a bug. Nevertheless I will try to upgrade and see what I find

Comment: Mathematica is very complex software. In any large complicated software, there will always be bugs which get fixed with time. The trick is to keep the level of adding bugs balanced with the amount of new code being added :)

Comment: I deleted the answer I posted earlier. I do get the same results Nasser is reporting, i.e. a Piecewise function for the general n case, and I Sqrt[3] for the specific n=3 case.  You appear to be comparing two different things in Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica. The equation at the top has a denorminator with a fixed constant 3, and your other cases mainly have a variable n in the denominator, which will vary as the iterator goes through its values. You might want to replace Sum with Table and compare terms. Sum basically just adds these list elements together.

Comment: @jdp Why does the variable $n$ vary with the iterator? The iterator iterates on $k$ so $n$ should be a constant w.r.t to it. Finally when $n$ gets substituted it should simplify to the correct value

Comment: I guess put another way, whats the difference between iterator variables and normal variables for substitution. Can I flag the $n$ somehow to not be an iterator?

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal, I get `I Sqrt[3]` both in 13.3.0 and 12.3.1. Looking at your code, it is easy to see where the problem is. Your `n` is [_black_](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlJ6f.png) which means you have set a value to it, most likely to `n = 2`. The replacement you do in the end therefore doesn't have any effect on the calculation. Use `Clear[n]` before evaluating your `Sum`, or wrap it in `Block[{n}, Sum[...] /. n->3]`.

Comment: In your first screenshot, notice that `n` is black.  That means that you've defined `n` somewhere above in your code. Can you do `Clear[n]`, then run that code again?  Here's what I get in V12: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xZ9H.png.

Comment: Yes that fixed it! Thank you all!! :)